# Event emitter in Angular unit test isn't called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, click, angular-event-emitter

Given this component ...

```js
export class MyComponent {
  @Output() onActivateEditMode = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() {}

  emitActivateEditMode(flag: boolean) {
    this.onActivateEditMode.emit(flag);
  }
```

... and this template ...

```html
<a (click)="emitActivateEditMode(true)" data-test-start-edit-project-btn>Edit</a>
```

... then this test fails:

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {

  ... (TestBed imports etc)

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(component, 'emitActivateEditMode');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should activate editmode on click', () => {
    const onActivateEditModeSpy = jest.spyOn(
      component.onActivateEditMode,
      'emit'
    );
    const startEditProjectBtn = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector(
      '[data-test-start-edit-project-btn]'
    );
    startEditProjectBtn.dispatchEvent(new Event('click')); // startEditProjectBtn.click() doesn't change the result, too
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.onActivateEditMode.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
    // expect(onActivateEditModeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true) ... doesn't change the result, too
  });

});
```

Test output is:

```
Expected: true
Number of calls: 0
```

The functionality works in the browser, but something on this test setup is wrong.

Comment: Don't spy on parts of the system under test. If you want to check the component `@Output` emits, use e.g. https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-inside-a-test-host.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Jasmine and Jest at the same time. The issue is that when you're spying on the function (`spyOn`), you're essentially just spying on the function for calls and the implementation details go away. To have the implementation details in tact, you can do `spyOn(component, 'emitActivateEditMode').and.callThrough();` but I think for you, it is not needed.

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {

  ... (TestBed imports etc)

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // remove the mock/spyOn to the function emitActivateEditMode
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should activate editmode on click', () => {
    // spy on emit calls on onActivatedEditMode
    const emitSpy = spyOn(component.onActivateEditMode, 'emit');
    const startEditProjectBtn = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector(
      '[data-test-start-edit-project-btn]'
    );
    startEditProjectBtn.click();
    fixture.detectChanges(); // fixture.detectChanges is not needed here, only if you want to see the update in the HTML.
    expect(emitSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
});
```